# Predict feature against specific labels among set of labels in multi-class classification

Tags: classification, keras, multiclass-classification

I have the following code in keras for multiclass classification:

```
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation=’relu’, input_shape=(8,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation=’relu’))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation=’relu’))
model.add(Dense(4, activation=’softmax’))
model.compile(loss=’categorical_crossentropy’, optimizer=’adam’, metrics=[‘accuracy’])

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, dummy_y, test_size=0.33, random_state=seed)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

**Question**: Above, we have **50 classes**, so after training when I do `model.predict()`, it will return probabilities for 50 classes and the one with largest value is associated to the input. Suppose I would like to predict feature/input against arbitrary 10 labels **after model training** only and not 50 classes, any hint/idea how to do that please?

Comment: Its not possible with the model you are training.

Comment: @Ashwiniku918. Is it possible in general with another model that has softmax output layer as the problem I am working with is for multiclass classification please? The problem is that I want to predict against only 10 labels and not 50 labels after training, so not sure if it's possible to do that with different architecture?